Plotly shows as blank black box within jupyterlab
I am trying to run plotly within jupyter lab in Azure. In the past it used to work but now all I see are blank boxes.

However, the following renders: right click on output box > This Frame > Open Frame in New Tab

I am running plotly as follows
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio 
pio.renderers.default = 'iframe'

num_rows = 50

# Generate random data for the columns
genes = [f'gene_{i}' for i in range(1, num_rows + 1)]
values = np.random.rand(num_rows)
treatments = np.random.choice(['treatment_A', 'treatment_B'], num_rows)

# Create the DataFrame
long = pd.DataFrame({
    'gene': genes,
    'value': values,
    'treatment': treatments
})


fig = px.box(
    long, x='gene', y='value', 
        color='treatment'
    )
fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black', showgrid=False)

fig.update_layout(
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)', 
    yaxis = dict( tickmode = 'linear', tick0 = 0, dtick = 2), 
    xaxis = dict( tickmode = 'linear', tick0 = 0, dtick = 1), 
    width=1200, 
    height=600)
fig.show()

I have tried other renderers (iframe-connected, notebook, azure) but to no avail. Why do I not see the output below but see it if I open it in a new tab?

Which version of JupyterLab are you using?
